# GStreamer showing error after overnight camera capture

Tags: camera, gstreamer, imx6

I am getting below error after running camera capture overnight.

it is running fine upto so many captures(200 to 300), but after that suddenly it shows below message and it is not able to take camera capture.
The iterations are not fixed or can't say that after this number only it is stopping capture.

As I have googled it I found similar issues to this, but couldn't found exact results....

```
gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2videosrc device=/dev/video1 input=0 imx-capture-mode=0 fps-n=15 ! imxeglvivsink
display(/dev/fb0) resolution is (800x480).
[INFO]  Product Info: i.MX6Q/D/S
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock




ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstImxV4l2VideoSrc:imxv4l2videosrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
../../../../gstreamer-1.6.3/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(2943): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstImxV4l2VideoSrc:imxv4l2videosrc0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
Execution ended after 0:00:10.172558001
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...

Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Please help me if you have any idea about the gstreamer issues, and the reasons when this type of error comes.

Answer (score 0):

Possibility is that,

1. Insufficient memory after long run of capture.
2. Camera input (frame timing) is not sync with iMX
3. System is in high CPU load